# Can't find the include file

Tags: html, npm, ejs

Im trying to include some messages in my ejs template welcome.ejs and its coming from messages.ejs.
Im doing my include as it's shows

```
<%- include ('views/partials/messages.ejs;') %>
```

'''[image: Heres is all my files in the project]

Heres is all my files in the project

But im getting this error:

[image]

I have already tried npm install and change the path to  <%- include ('partials/messages;') %> but still he could not find the file.

Answer (score 0):

in app.js You should set the path to view by

> app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
>    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

then include your partials by:

Comment: i mean add the include file by <%- include('partials/messages') %>